# How to apply contour to z matrix which has the same dimension as x- and y matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

My dataset contains x, y coordinate and energy surface z. I need to turn those into [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyINI.jpg). The problem is that z need to have the dimension of (x, y) but all three of them are 1D numpy array with length = 10201 (also some values in z are inf). I tried to turn z into a meshgrid with

```
Z, Z = np.meshgrid(z,z)
```

and then try

```
ax.contour(x, y, Z)
```

but the result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV10B.jpg). How should it do it?

I tried to turn z into a meshgrid, tried to remove all the rows which contain inf value in z, tried to turn all three of them into meshgrids

Comment: `10201 = 101*101`, so I'd say `X, Y, Z = (vec.reshape(101,101) for vec in (x, y, z)) ; plt.contour(X, Y, Z)`